# Gcam not working on my Custom GSI-installed phone

Tags: java, android, custom-rom

I installed a custom gsi on my phone, Infinix Hot 20s (X6827), which is the unofficial version of Evolution X GSI. My phone only supports FULL in Camera2API. And the only problem is there's no RAW support. Is that the problem?

When I try to run GCAM, it crashes and I copied the error code:

```
time: 1706363340161

msg: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.googlex.gcam.Gcam.g()' on a null object reference

stacktrace: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.googlex.gcam.Gcam.g()' on a null object reference

    at iql.run(Unknown Source:3007)

    at bya.run(Unknown Source:2355)

    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)

    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)

    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)

    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8282)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:554)

    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.googlex.gcam.Gcam.g()' on a null object reference

    at dul.CMfxtQMHPwuVyDyx(Unknown Source:0)

    at dul.get(Unknown Source:1452)

    at nty.dsZDTulkdTGroEeU(Unknown Source:0)

    at nty.get(Unknown Source:69)

    at eff.a(Unknown Source:5)

    at dsg.get(Unknown Source:1474)

    at nty.dsZDTulkdTGroEeU(Unknown Source:0)

    at nty.get(Unknown Source:69)

    at drv.get(Unknown Source:871)

    at nty.dsZDTulkdTGroEeU(Unknown Source:0)

    at nty.get(Unknown Source:69)

    at hmk.get(Unknown Source:1085)

    at nty.dsZDTulkdTGroEeU(Unknown Source:0)

    at nty.get(Unknown Source:69)

    at ejz.get(Unknown Source:1955)

    at nty.dsZDTulkdTGroEeU(Unknown Source:0)

    at nty.get(Unknown Source:69)

    at ntx.NrVKpQbZqesVFJhH(Unknown Source:0)

    at ntx.get(Unknown Source:24)

    at bzt.d(Unknown Source:216)

    at bzt.a(Unknown Source:37)

    at ceu.run(Unknown Source:457)

    ... 9 more
```

Installing another version now giving new error:

```
t

ime: 1706363667762

msg: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference

stacktrace: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference

    at lew.run(Unknown Source:3037)

    at dtd.run(Unknown Source:3010)

    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)

    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)

    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)

    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8282)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:554)

    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference

    at flu.get(Unknown Source:1432)

    at pxh.get(Unknown Source:27)

    at fnf.get(Unknown Source:2356)

    at pxh.get(Unknown Source:27)

    at jwq.get(Unknown Source:1153)

    at pxh.get(Unknown Source:27)

    at gjf.get(Unknown Source:572)

    at pxh.get(Unknown Source:27)

    at pxg.get(Unknown Source:38)

    at dwo.d(Unknown Source:236)

    at dwo.a(Unknown Source:32)

    at eaj.run(Unknown Source:3602)

    ... 9 more
```

Can't I really use GCAM?

Tried LMC 8.4 gives the same error.
Tried on other GSIs, also not working.